# HTTP Status mapping/equivalency to .NET exceptions

Tags: .net, exception, http-status-codes

### Background

I'm currently implementing a HTTP Module that is responsible for monitoring some usage behaviors and gracefully handle uncaught application errors via `BeginRequest`, `EndRequest` and `Error` events from the current `HttpApplication` context.

### Question

Is there a straightforward, already implemented way to map .NET platform exceptions to their HTTP equivalents? A few examples comes to mind:

```
FileNotFoundException       > 404 File Not Found
UnauthorizedAccessException > 403 Forbidden
AuthenticationException     > 401 Unauthorized
[...]
(Any unmapped exception)    > 500 Internal Server Error
```

I don't want to possibly reinvent the wheel, so any hints/directions are appreciated.